# 2:1 Mux in VHDL- signal not changing value

Tags: vhdl, fpga, mux

I am trying to make a 2:1 (8 bit wide) mux in VHDL. Here's what I have:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity lab1 is
    Port ( SEL : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Y   : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           X   : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           M   : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end lab1;

architecture Behavioral of lab1 is
signal internal: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
begin
    process (X, Y, SEL)
    begin
    if SEL = '0' then
        internal <= X;
     else 
        internal <= Y;
     end if;
    end process;
    M <= internal;
end Behavioral;
```

And my test bench file looks like this:

```
LIBRARY ieee;                                               
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;                                

ENTITY lab1_vhd_tst IS
END lab1_vhd_tst;
ARCHITECTURE lab1_arch OF lab1_vhd_tst IS
-- constants                                                 
-- signals                                                   
SIGNAL M : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL SEL : STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL X : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL Y : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
COMPONENT lab1
    PORT (
    M : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
    SEL : IN STD_LOGIC;
    X : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
    Y : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0)
    );
END COMPONENT;
BEGIN
    i1 : lab1
    PORT MAP (
-- list connections between master ports and signals
    M => M,
    SEL => SEL,
    X => X,
    Y => Y
    );
init : PROCESS                                               
-- variable declarations                                     
BEGIN                                                        
        -- code that executes only once                      
WAIT;                                                       
END PROCESS init;                                           
always : PROCESS                                              
-- optional sensitivity list                                  
-- (        )                                                 
-- variable declarations                                      
BEGIN                                                         
        -- code executes for every event on sensitivity list  
          X <= "11111111";
          Y <= "00000000";
          SEL <= '0';
          wait for 10 ns;
          SEL <= '1';
          wait for 10 ns;
WAIT;                                                        
END PROCESS always;                                          
END lab1_arch;
```

When I simulate it, the output of the SELECT signal, and subsequently the M (output) signal do not change, even though I am updating the value of the SEL signal after a few waits in the test bench file.

Here's what the waveform looks like for reference:
[image]

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using `internal` instead of just assigning directly to `M`?

Comment: @skrrgwasme not really. I have tried it both ways.

Comment: You have written your tests incorrectly it seems, plus there is no need for `internal` signal. You can see an example [here](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2V3e)

Comment: ignoring the noise, [your simulation seems to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMfr1.jpg). That leaves an issue with the process you used to produce the results. Have you recently edited the testbench (are you running the right testbench)?

Comment: @user1155120 yes im using the right one. If I change the values of X or Y in the testbench that's reflected on the waveform

Comment: Note your waveform display starts after the change of `SEL` to '1' at 10 ns which selects  `Y` ("00000000"). Your waveform doesn't display `M` with the value of `X`. The waveform provided in a comment shows time 0 to 20 ns and shows the value of `X` on `M`.